# Запуск нескольких скриптов в питоне с помощью одной программы

Tags: python

Есть небольшая проблема, у меня есть 10 скриптов на питоне с названиями main_1.py, main_2.py и т.д, могу ли я создать отдельный скрипт на питоне, при запуске которого будут запускаться все эти 10 скриптов?

Если есть то дайте пожалуйста ссылочку на этот способ, очень хочется изучить вопрос.

Я вычитал про subprocess и про os, но я не уверен что с их помощью я смогу запустить что-то более одного - двух скриптов.

Comment: Почему не сможете? Там нет ограничения на количество.

Comment: То есть мне нужно просто создать функцию в которую передать что-то вот такое?
`subprocess.Popen(['python3', 'script.py', 'argzzz1', 'argzzz2'])
`
И можно ли это проставить на 10 скриптов просто добавив timesleep?

Comment: Просто в цикле или последовательно вызвать, к примеру, subprocess.Popen() с разными скриптами.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!